# On start up a website it will redirect to another url in the same domain

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect, iis, web-config

I need to redirect the site url on start up.
my site link is like `http://www.test.com` when load the site it will automatically redirect to `http://www.test.com/ar` .

I just try `<location path="http://www.test.com/ar">`

But it not working..

Can any one help how can we achieve this..Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=/ar">
```

Comment: Hi.It is working fine but I can't switch to English site back.I set this meta tag in master template..Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Try it in the code behind :

**On your `.aspx.cs` file of the web page `test.com` :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Server.Transfer("http://www.test.com/ar");
}
```